# What is the difference between Infrastructure and application endpoints in WCF (in lay terms)?

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm struggling to find a Layman's definition of the difference between an Application Endpoint and an Infrastructure Endpoint in WCF

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731079%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) defines the distinction as follows:

**application endpoint**

```
An endpoint exposed by the application and that corresponds to a service contract implemented by the application.
```

**infrastructure endpoint**

```
An endpoint that is exposed by the infrastructure to facilitate functionality that is needed or provided by the service that does not relate to a service contract. For example, a service might have an infrastructure endpoint that provides metadata information.
```

Would an example of the latter be an endpoint that informed a client endpoint how to handle paticular kinds of Bindings? Please could someone provide a less abstract scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An *Infrastructure Endpoint* says things about the service. E.g. something that implements [IMetaDataExchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.imetadataexchange(v=vs.110).aspx).

> When programming Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) services, it
>   is useful to publish metadata about the service. For example, metadata
>   can be a Web Services Description Language (WSDL) document that
>   describes all of the methods and data types employed by a service.
>   Returning metadata about an WCF service allows consumers of a service
>   to easily create clients for the service.

Where as an *Application Endpoint* does something, e.g what you annotate in WCF with `Operation Contract`.

Comment: Thanks! That straightens it out!